# How to check id of one table to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to find whether distinct value id of one table exits to another tables or not using php.

For example: Let `table1` have `id` (not primary or unique) `4`, `5`, `6`, `4`, `6`, how to check if `id` of `table2` have `4`, `5`, `6` or not ?

```
$query_check= "select distinct(project_code) from table1";
$projects_check = mysql_query($query_check);

while ($result_check = mysql_fetch_array($projects_check)){
    $all[] = $result_check[0];  
}

$query = "select id from table2";
$projects = mysql_query($query);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($projects)){
    foreach($all as $all_val){
        $pro_code = $result[0];
        if($pro_code != $all_val){ }
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Please post your related table structures (`create table code`)

Comment: i mention some php code above..

Comment: What do you want the result to be? a boolean? or the tables id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SQL may help:

```
SELECT table2.id 
FROM table2
WHERE table2.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT table1.id
    FROM table1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table2.id 
FROM table2
WHERE table2.id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT table1.id
    FROM table1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all the project codes from table1 that are ids in table2:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.project_code  
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.project_code = table2.id
```

To get a list of all the project codes from table1 that are NOT ids in table2

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.project_code  
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.project_code = table2.id
WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

If it is the entries on 2 that you want that are not on 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.id  
FROM table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1
ON table1.project_code = table2.id
WHERE table1.project_code IS NULL
```

Comment: table2.id IS NULL is for what ?

Comment: But I need to select id of table 2

Comment: The first query lists all the entries from table1 that are on table2 (which is what I thought you wanted). The 2nd gives you all the entries on table1 that are NOT on table2 (it does a LEFT OUTER JOIN, then checks table2.id for being NULL - ie, no match found).

Comment: u select from table1, it may show the values of table1

Comment: I cannot work out what else it is you want? Put up some test data with records on both table1 and table2, and which ones you want output.

Comment: I need data of table2. If table2 contains id,name then how I need to query? Bcoz there are id in both tables so I m confused

Comment: `table2 = (4,'xyz'),(5,'abc'),(6,'pqr') table1 = (3,4,3,6) `.....  I want only (5,'abc') of table2

Comment: That is what the last query will give you.

Comment: Just add the extra field to the SELECt . Ie _SELECT DISTINCT table2.id  , table2.name_

Comment: ur query was SELECT DISTINCT table1.project_code.... I need to try with SELECT DISTINCT table2.project_code ????

Comment: The project_code field is on table1. You said you want the fields from table2 which appear to be _id_ and _name_ . Hence _SELECT DISTINCT table2.id , table2.name FROM table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table1.project_code = table2.id WHERE table1.project_code IS NULL_ . If the id on table2 is unique then you do not need the DISTINCT

Comment: thnk you, really appreciated

Comment: I have set up your test data and used the query in the comment above and it gives the data you have said you want. Note that JOINs tend to perform better than using IN with a sub query .